# Store procedure oracle con varias consultas al mismo tiempo

Tags: sql, oracle

Hola quiero ejecutar 2 consultas en 2 tablas diferentes con un solo store procedure.

```
    BEGIN
        UPDATE personal
        SET imei_equipo = v_imei WHERE PERSONAL_ID = v_personal_id;
    BEGIN
        UPDATE lugar
        SET latitud = v_latitud SET longitud=v_longitud WHERE LUGAR_ID = v_lugar_id;

        COMMIT;
```

Algo  asi pero que funcione jajaja
Pd> una sola consulta si me funciona

Answer (score 2):

El problema con tu ejemplo es que tienes varios `begin`. Solo necesitas uno:

```
create procedure procname as
begin
    UPDATE personal
       SET imei_equipo = v_imei WHERE PERSONAL_ID = v_personal_id;

    UPDATE lugar
       SET latitud = v_latitud SET longitud=v_longitud WHERE LUGAR_ID = v_lugar_id;

    commit;
end;
/
```